# Unlock Jenkins - how to

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have installed jenkins on my ec2 instance using putty, from my windows system

When I try to access jenkins through web, I get the Unlock Jenkins using /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYLJe.png)
How to get to this location as if accessing through putty, I get permission denied to this folder.

Please advise, I am new to ubuntu and jenkins

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My solution is similar to the one by Mark B, I viewed the secrets by executing the cat command on the initialAdminPassword file.

However, I was not able to use cat to view the password until I gave my user permission.

Initially jenkins was the only user that had permissions to do anything with the secrets folder. I tried logging into the jenkins user account but could not.  I executed:

`sudo chmod a+rwx ./secrets`

to give myself permission to view that directory.

As some background information, it might seem weird that I would give myself permission to "execute" a directory, but that is necessary in order to view its in the terminal using ls.

Also, my account is an admin account. I am running MacOS 10.11.4. Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I had to do the same with the initialAdminPassword file (you can just set ``rw`` on that one obviously).

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me in a raspberry pi as well, where sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword did not work initially.

Answer (score 12):

Try accessing the file using *sudo*:

```
sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

Comment: yes `sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword` worked for me, thanks

Comment: yes the command sudo cat  /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On the terminal, where you have connected to the Ubuntu EC2 instance, view the content of the file using the command `sudo cat <path copied from the jenkins page>`. It will show the default administrator password. You can copy and use this password in the GUI (browser) to log in first time.