# Unlock Jenkins on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on an ec2 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server based on these instructions: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-18-04/

When I go to Jenkins in my browser I get the "Unlock Jenkins" page:

> Unlock Jenkins To ensure Jenkins is securely set up by the
>   administrator, a password has been written to the log (not sure where
>   to find it?) and this file on the server:
>
> /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
>
> Please copy the password from either location and paste it below.
>
> ERROR: The password entered is incorrect, please check the file for
>   the correct password

But the folder /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/ does not contain the initialAdminPassword file.

I tried temporarily turning off security based on
[How to reset Jenkins security settings from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988849/how-to-reset-jenkins-security-settings-from-the-command-line)
but the "useSecurity" tag in config.xml gets reset to "true" every time I restart Jenkins.

I also tried this, but was still not able to find the password file
[Unlock Jenkins - how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426111/unlock-jenkins-how-to)

Comment: It looks like you entered a password. Which one did you use? 
Is there the password in the install log from apt? 
What files does `/var/lib/jenkins/secrets/` contain?

Comment: I didn't enter a password. Sorry, I don't know how to block quote from a response. The secrets folder contains: 

> filepath-filters.d

> hudson.console.AnnotatedLargeText.consoleAnnotator

> hudson.console.ConsoleNote.MAC

> hudson.model.Job.serverCookie

> hudson.util.Secret

> jenkins.model.Jenkins.crumbSalt

> master.key

> org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices.mac

> org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.InstanceIdentity.KEY

> slave-to-master-security-kill-switch

> whitelisted-callables.d

Comment: Also, I should mention that there is no mention of a password in the jenkins logs

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

before running

```
 sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

and because of that, your system repo could not got updated and hence you installed an earlier unpatched version.

so follow full procedure without skipping any steps:

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```